# Reducing badge number with Push notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push

Hi in my application when i receive  push notification from server my application badge get incremented by one.and when i open app and close it did not get reduce.so my question is how to reduce badge icon on application icon when user see the notification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it to any value you like. Setting it to 0 removes the badge.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, so I thought, "Why not just GET the badge number?" Then, you can do whatever you wish with it.

If you are in your AppDelegate.m file, you could use this in your `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
int badgeNumber = [application applicationIconBadgeNumber] -1;
[application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeNumber];
```

This will reduce the icon badge number by one.  However, be mindful that your user may have multiple notifications from your application that are still not yet viewed.  Thus, you should probably set this inside of a particular method that will handle the pushes.  Or, depending how your app is set up, just set the badge icon number to 0.

Hope this helps.